# csvhelper import ignores delimiter when double quote is inside a field

Tags: csvhelper

I am using CSVHelper to import csv data into a table, I noticed that the following string breaks my import and I end up with my data shifted on all fields after the fourth field.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with the 10" (inches symbol) in my data:

```
    "111111-B","EERRTT",1,"*SPECIAL* Tire 10"","front black & red fill img***",101.53,101.53,"20180427","","",""
```

Here is my configuration:

```
    var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<InvolineMap>();
    csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
    csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
```

Here is my Map:

```
    public sealed class InvolineMap : ClassMap<Involine>
    {
        public InvolineMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Id).Ignore();
            Map(m => m.INVOICEREF).Index(0);
            Map(m => m.CATNO).Index(1);
            Map(m => m.QUAN).Index(2);
            Map(m => m.DONE).Index(3);
            Map(m => m.DTWO).Index(4);
            Map(m => m.UNIT).Index(5);
            Map(m => m.TOTAL).Index(6);
            Map(m => m.DATE).Index(7);
            Map(m => m.VOID).Index(8);
            Map(m => m.COM1).Index(9);
            Map(m => m.COM2).Index(10);
            Map(m => m.OrderId).Ignore();
            Map(m => m.Line).Ignore();
        }
    }
```

How do I ignore the inches symbol?
Also, I have the option to replace the " character for a ^ as the text qualifier but I don't see an option to change the text qualifier in CSVHelper, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The source CSV has been improperly escaped.

The double quotes signifying inches should be escaped with another double quote character (see [RFC4180 Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) item 7).

`... "1","*SPECIAL* Tire 10""","front black & red fill img***" ...`

To read a CSV using `^` as your text qualifier instead of `"`, you could set the `Quote` property in the [CsvHelper Configuration](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/configuration/#formatting):

```
csv.Configuration.Quote = '^';
```

This may help you to avoid issues with this specific file but you will likely run into problems later on when you encounter a text field that contains `^`.